# SQL Server - Linked Server using ASEOLEDB

Tags: sql-server, sybase, linked-server

Has anyone managed to get a linked server working between SQL 2008R2 and Sybase ASE 15.7 using the SAP/Sybase OLE DB driver and not using an ODBC DSN?

I've tried what seems like every combination of parameters to create the linked server both through the GUI and using `sp_addlinkedserver`, all to no avail.

If you could supply an example `sp_addlinkedserver` call that would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you seen this [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) And [This](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/280102)?

Comment: Thanks shA.t but the BoL article doesn't provide an example of the ASEOLEDB, and the second article uses an ODBC DSN which I don't want to do.